# OKTA Connection Timeout Issues for Github Login Using Gatling Recorder

Tags: github, okta, scala-gatling

I am trying to perform UI load testing on Github which is secured using Saml Authentication during Login.
I am using Gatling recorder to record the below steps-
(open inspect -network tab)
step1- launch Github url
step2-enter username
step3-enter password
step4-click verify
 
Download "HAR" file from network tab which will contain recorded calls.
Go to Gatling recorder and convert HAR file to Scala file
When i execute this scala file in Intellij -i am facing some issues related to okta -
 
---- Errors --------------------------------------------------------------------

> i.n.c.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: ok2static    
> .oktacdn.com/
> i.n.c.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: login.okt    
> a.com/
> ===============================================================================
>  
>  
> Below are the Okta related keywords which i see in API network calls->
> RelayState,Signature,SAML Request,SignAlg,Service Token etc

can someone pls help -How can i handle okta authentication in my scala script?

1)I tried adding proxy related to Okta and my organization specific proxy urls in my Gatling script- but no gain.

2)I tried Manually copying pasting cookie in subsequent request -but not worked

I am strucked at login itself due to okta connection timeout issues